# Better way to visualize a social network graph

Tags: graph, visualization

I have graph of friendship of one social network with about 1.5 million of nodes and 17 million edges - not all network, but that's enough for me. 
Of course, it's undirected and unweighted.
What is the way to render it really beautiful? (e.g. to make a poster ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try with [Gephi](http://www.gephi.org). This is a very large graph but I think you can handle it with a correct computer.

I advice you to try **OpenOrd** ([here](http://gephi.org/plugins/openord-layout/)) or **ForceAtlas in Parallel version** ([here](http://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1231))

You can render as SVG or PDF to export you graph for "graphic customization"

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Protovis ( http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/) especially ForceDirectedLayout
http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/force.html

Comment: My experience with Protovis is that it can't possibly render graphs that large.